# Property getAllKeys does not exists on type IDBIndex

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript2.0

Build is fine, since i'm using a transpiler (rollup).

But VSCode is highlighting one file related to some operations with IndexedDB.

I found that vscode is getting the lib.dom.d.ts file from somewhere in program files instead of this one https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts which includes getAllKeys.

I missing something here :(

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

EDIT - adding info:
 Latest vscode version, with included ts v2.9.2.
 TsConfig target: es2017
 Tried almost all lib combinations.

Update 1:
 Included webworker in libs and still nothing. It's weird since it's here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/cca2631a90fb414f7c830f2d2895a3b5f0db896f/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was added "recently" and it's not part of the release.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24850

I will ignore this error and move on, until this feature lands.

Will also try to edit manually my local d.ts and add the methods needed.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/cca2631a90fb414f7c830f2d2895a3b5f0db896f/lib/lib.webworker.d.ts